# Get a list of users who are Domain Admins and have not logged in the past 30 days?

Tags: active-directory, powershell

How can I get a list of users from AD who are Domain Admins and have not logged in the past 30 days?

Comment: Welcome to [sf]! What have you tried so far?

Comment: If my updated answer does what you need it to, please feel free to click the up arrow next to my answer to upvote it and mark the answer as correct by clicking the checkmark next to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

user360071, here is a PowerShell script that will do what you want.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Age = 30
$When = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-$Age)).Date
$Members = (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Domain Admins" -Recursive).DistinguishedName
Foreach ($Member in $Members) {
Get-ADUser -Identity $Member -Property LastLogonDate | Where LastLogonDate -lt $When | Select SamAccountName,UserPrincipalName,LastLogonDate | Export-CSV -Path $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\users.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

You can make a small change so you can pick how long you want to look for an account that has not logged in. Here is the changed version.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Age = Read-Host "Accounts that have not been logged into in the last how many days should be shown?"
$When = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-$Age)).Date
$Members = (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Domain Admins" -Recursive).DistinguishedName
Foreach ($Member in $Members) {
Get-ADUser -Identity $Member -Property LastLogonDate | Where LastLogonDate -lt $When | Select SamAccountName,UserPrincipalName,LastLogonDate | Export-CSV -Path $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\users.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

**Updated Answer**

Hello user360071. When you want to add another request to your question or need to clarify what you are trying to ask you can edit your question and save the changes.

In your addition you added that you want to be able to save the results to an Excel file.

You tried `>> users.csv` but the Excel file is empty. In PowerShell what you want to do is `| Export-CSV users.csv`. The scripts have been updated with this.

Comment: Don't forget to recourse the domain admins group just in case there are nested groups. You might also want to query the domain's "Administrators" group in case some accounts get added there as well.

Comment: @SturdyErde thanks for the idea. I added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To implement user5870571's suggestion with `>> users.csv` (in case your file is blank - mine was too) do the following:

1) save the below script to a .ps1 file. Note that I removed `Export-Csv`

```
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory
    $Age = Read-Host "Accounts that have not been logged into in the last how many days should be shown?"
    $When = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-$Age)).Date
    $Members = (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Domain Admins" -Recursive).DistinguishedName
    Foreach ($Member in $Members) {
    Get-ADUser -Identity $Member -Property LastLogonDate | Where LastLogonDate -lt $When | Select SamAccountName,UserPrincipalName,LastLogonDate
}
```

2) once you saved the file, navigate to it from an elevated powershell prompt and add `>> users.csv` at the end.

For example, I named my file `get-dausers.ps1` and saved it on desktop, opened a powershell prompt and navigated to it, then typed `.\get-dausers.ps1 >> users.csv` - this will generate a .csv file on the desktop and it will not be empty anymore.

Answer (score 0):

To build on user5870571's post -

I would recommend using the `LastLogonTimestamp` property of the ADUser account, instead of the `LastLogonDate`.

[lastLogon vs. lastLogonTimestamp in Active Directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/734615/lastlogon-vs-lastlogontimestamp-in-active-directory)

- Lastlogon is only updated on the domain controller that performs the authentication and is not replicated.
- LastLogontimestamp is replicated, but by default only if it is 14 days or more older than the previous value.

Below is the updated code.  I also added the "sort by LastLogon" because I think it's useful.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Age = Read-Host "Accounts that have not been logged into in the last how many days should be shown?"

$When = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-$Age)).Date

$Members = (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Domain Admins" -Recursive).DistinguishedName

Foreach ($Member in $Members) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter {DistinguishedName -eq $Member} -Property LastLogonTimestamp | Where {([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogonTimestamp)) -lt $When} |
    Select SamAccountName,UserPrincipalName,@{Name="LastLogon";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogonTimestamp)}} | Sort-Object LastLogon |
    Export-CSV -Path $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\users.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```